# count values in multivalue field

Tags: solr

I need to count how many fields has a multivalue field to sort results out.

solrconfig.xml

```xml
  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-numbers-count">
 <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
   <str name="source">cat_ids</str>
   <str name="dest">cat_ids_count</str>
 </processor>
 <processor class="solr.CountFieldValuesUpdateProcessorFactory">
   <str name="fieldName">cat_ids_count</str>
 </processor>
 <processor class="solr.DefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory">
   <str name="fieldName">cat_ids_count</str>
   <int name="value">0</int>
 </processor>
 <!-- <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
 <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />  -->
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
  <initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/spell">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">_text_</str>
             <str name="update.chain">add-numbers-count</str>

    </lst>
  </initParams>
```

manageschema.xml

```xml
 <field name="cat_ids" type="plongs"/>
  <field name="cat_ids_count" type="pint"/>
```

Note that `RunUpdateProcessorFactory` and `LogUpdateProcessorFactory` are commented out.

If I use them update fails with a non sense error:

> ERROR: [doc=44996] Error adding field 'data_readout'='2025-06-01' msg=Invalid Date String:'2025-06-01'int(44996)

Solr is not creating this field `cat_ids_count` I guess because there is no `RunUpdateProcessorFactory`.

Do I have to delete and recreate collection? Or is there any error I can't see?

Comment: You _have_ to include those processors - otherwise your code is essentially no-op, since those are the entries in the update processor chain that _actually submits the content to Solr_. Instead you should fix the content submitted for your date field to the expectected format, `YYYY-mm-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`

Comment: But, why if I op out processors this error doesn't come up?. It gets me crazy, because it is no sense.

Comment: If you comment out the processors, nothing gets submitted to Solr. If nothing gets submitted to Solr, Solr has nothing to complain about. It makes sense - if you don't actually give Solr anything to validate, there can't be any validation errors. The update processor runs before Solr gets anything to work with, which is why you need to those instructions - to actually send it to the next step inside Solr.